# Using same component multiple times with same reducer and state variables instance for each called component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using custom-closable-tabs.js to create tabs for my application which makes use of react and react-redux for state management. I have a scenario where I need to open multiple tabs of same component within the application.Consider I have a main home component which has 3 user links and these users have same component but with different data, say if clicked on user1 `<User name="Jon" />` component will be loaded in a new tab[Tab1] where an API call is made to fetch details of the user "Jon" from the database and store the data in redux state. Similarly for the second user[Tab2] `<User name="Eve">` again an API call is made to retrieve details of user "Eve" and store in the same reducer.

As I am making use of same reducer for the both the users, data of "Eve" is reflected in Tab1 where Jon's data was displayed earlier. 
How do I create reducers state instance for each component separately that can retrieve data for individual user and display in respective tabs, here users are populated dynamically.

App Component

```
class App extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: '',
        activeIndex: 0
    }
}

componentWillMount(){
    this.state.data.push({
        tab: Maintab,
        component: <Main/>,
        id: maintab,
        closeable: false,
        activeIndex: 0
    })
}

openTab(user){
    this.state.data.push({
        tab: user,
        component: <User userName={user}/>,
        id: user,
        closeable: true,
        activeIndex: (this.state.data.length-1)
    })
}


render(){
    return(
        <CloseableTabs 
        data={this.state.data}
        noTabUnmount={true}
        activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex}
        />
    );
}
```

Main Component

```
render(){
return(
    <div>
        <div onCLick={()=>{this.props.openTab('Jon')}}>User1: Jon</div>
        <div onCLick={()=>{this.props.openTab('Eve')}}>User2: Eve</div>
        <div onCLick={()=>{this.props.openTab('Seth')}}>User3: Seth</div>
    </div>
);}
```

User Component

```
componentDidMount(){
    //Make Api call and store data in reducer with action GET_USER_INFO
}

render(){
    const {father,mother,company} = this.props
    return(
        <div>
            <span>Father:{father}</span>
            <span>Mother:{mother}</span>
            <span>Company:{company}</span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Reducer

```
const users = (state,action) =>{
switch(action.type){
    case 'GET_USER_INFO':
        return{userData: action.value.userData}
}}
```

Comment: Hi @rock , welcome to SO :) Please read the info given here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , that will help the community to help you more quickly !

Comment: why u need to add each userdata as state if you are getting the data from a api? or use props maybe?

Comment: @adel I am using the same user data for other component too, this component is not connected to User component hence I am storing it in redux.